# Is it posible to add ui-kit offcanves as a dropdown?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, uikit, getuikit

This offcanves I fond in ui-kit documation
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAbIW.png)

https://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas

How can I make my mobile navigation like this?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plK8o.png)